# Dynamically create row with data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an event application.  What I want is within a table, there will be three inputs and a button.  The user can input the event (ie vacation) and a start and end date. When the button is clicked I would like to know how I can dynamically take that info and create a new unique row with the information right underneath.

This new row will contain all the information from the inputs and have a delete button.

```
        <div class="container eventContainer">
        <table class="event">
            <thead class="titleContainer">
                <tr>
                    <td class="titleEvent">Event</td>
                    <td class="titleStartDate">Start Date</td>
                    <td class="titleEndDate">End date</td>
                    <td class="titleButton"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="eventInputMain">
                <tr>
                    <td class="eventInput">
                        <input type="text" name="Event" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="startDateInput">
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" id="startDatePicker">
                            <div class="inputImage"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="endDateInput">
                        <input type="text" id="endDatePicker">
                        <div class="inputImage"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="eventAdd">
                        <div class="eventAddIcon">
                            <div class="icon32 add"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: This is basic knowledge. Go get a jquery book and read a bit. It is even important for yourself.

Comment: Is there any code showing what you have tried to this point?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to prevent the default click event for the button .
2. You have to add a new div where you will put the information .
3. When the button is clicked you will use $(element).val() .
4. Display the data into the new div with $(element).html() .

P.S : If you want I can recommend a book for beginners .

HTML:

```
<div id="dataAnchor"> </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#button').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#dataAnchor').html($('#event').val() + $('#startDate').val() + $('#endDate').val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps

```
var trElement = $('<tr/>');
trElement.append('<td>'+$('#event').val()+'</td>');
trElement.append('<td>'+$('#startDatePicker').val()+'</td>');
trElement.append('<td>'+$('#endDatePicker').val()+'</td>');
trElement.append('<td><div class="eventAddIcon"><div class="icon32 remove"></div></div></td>');
$('.eventInputMain').append(trElement);
```

Thanks